# add my main activity toolbar to another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, android-toolbar

in my main activity i have a toolbar. also i have a layout with a Custom list view. i want to show that toolbar here too. but whatever i do i cant. what is the problem? i want the same toolbar from my main activity to be shown here too.

**About.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class About extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView list;
String[] text = {
        "Version"
} ;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp
};

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);

    // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar. (doesn't work)
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(About.this, text, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(About.this, "You Clicked at " + text[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

**about.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:background="@drawable/about_background">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `ListView` and `Toolbar` layout overlapping each other, that's why you are not able to see that. If you want to show `ListView` below the Toolbar then you have to set `android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"` property in `ListView` like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar
    android:background="@drawable/about_background">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i guessed that they are overlapping, but i didn't know how to fix it. thanks a lot.

Comment: one more thing. how can i add arrow back icon?

Comment: i found it:
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });